# MongoDB: merge raw object into nested structure

Tags: php, mongodb

I have an array object like this:

```
[ 
  'things'=>[ 
    't1'=>[ 'prop1'=>3 ] 
  ] 
]
```

and I want to merge it into the following collection entry:

```
[
  'id'=>123,
  'things'=>[
    't1'=>[ 'prop1'=>1, 'prop2'=>2 ],
    't2'=>[ 'prop1'=>1, 'prop2'=>2 ]
  ]
]
```

If I try to use the object as is, the following code deletes `things.t1.prop2` and `things.t2`:

```
$db_collection->update([ 'id'=>123 ], [ '$set'=>[ 'things'=>[ 't1'=>[ 'prop1'=>3 ] ] ] ]);
```

Probably I have to convert the object into the dot notation format like this:

```
$db_collection->update([ 'id'=>123 ], [ '$set'=>[ 'things.t1.prop1'=>3 ] ]);
```

I can also read the whole entry first, merge data with a specific function inside my script, and write the updated entry back into the database.

But these ways don't seem to be very efficient. Is there a special command in Mongo to incorporate a raw object into nested data without overwriting the whole entry?

P.S.: I'm using a PHP MongoDB driver.